# Is there any verification process/sanity check for installation of AEM/cq5?

Tags: aem

I started installation of AEM6.2 in local system, because of system freeze, i have aborted AEM start-up process before it extracts **"crx-quickstart"** folder completely.

Later i resumed the installation process by running the same aem-author-4502.jar file. After complete extraction of the jar file i found below two issues

1. ***side kick is not visible in the geometrixx websites***.
2. ***And also there system is not behaving as expected for the user admin console.***

**Is there any verification process or sanity check for the system stability and complete extraction process after installation of AEM** anything feature like report generation which can showcase about the AEM installation and all the OOTB needed features has installed properly.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify the below log files under crx-quickstart/logs for any errors during startup. which can be one way of verification.

> **stderr.log**
>
> Holds error messages, again of varying levels of severity,
> generated during startup. By default the log level is set to Warning
> (WARN)
>
> **stdout.log**
>
> Holds logging messages indicating events during
> startup.

Also you can get the JSON report of all your bundles by using http://localhost:4502/system/console/bundles.json url, and also you can use the [OOTB sanity check](http://www.aemstuff.com/tools/coi.html) comparison after any hot fixes installation. And for [across environments](http://www.aemstuff.com/tools/cti.html) comparison.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to `system/console/bundles` and see the active bundles (**x** bundles in total - all **x** bundles active) then it should give you a good idea of system stability. Bundles will fail to activate when components are missing. In your case these will be 'jar' files in bundles or related configs as you aborted the extraction.

You can also get a report like list from `system/console/status-Bundlelist` & `system/console/status-Bundlelist.txt` servlet which should give you a status of running bundles and any failures.

HTH